Cannot deploy to firebase hosting with CI: No OAuth tokens found
I tried to deploy my astro project into firebase hosting but i'm unable to deploy them with CI, but able to deploy them in my own machine. here is the log for the CI
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.760Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.906Z] [iam] checking project my-project for permissions ["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.908Z] No OAuth tokens found
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.911Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project:testIamPermissions [none]
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.911Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project:testIamPermissions x-goog-quota-user=projects/my-project
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.912Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]}
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.978Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project:testIamPermissions 200
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.978Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]}
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.980Z] No OAuth tokens found
[2024-10-21T08:50:57.981Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project [none]
[2024-10-21T08:50:58.191Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project 200
[2024-10-21T08:50:58.192Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-project {"my-project":"my-project","projectNumber":"885544713240","displayName":"My Project","name":"projects/my-project","resources":{"hostingSite":"my-project","storageBucket":"my-project.appspot.com","locationId":"asia-southeast1"},"state":"ACTIVE","etag":"1_9e3865a8-3d58-4604-8afd-2bef41db3846"}
[2024-10-21T08:51:51.951Z] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at findDependency (/home/builds/7Wjzy3dMG/0/project-dir/node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-tools@13.22.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/utils.js:188:23)
    at getNuxtVersion (/home/builds/7Wjzy3dMG/0/project-dir/node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-tools@13.22.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/nuxt/utils.js:9:45)
    at discover (/home/builds/7Wjzy3dMG/0/project-dir/node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-tools@13.22.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/nuxt2/index.js:25:48)
    at async discover (/home/builds/7Wjzy3dMG/0/project-dir/node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-tools@13.22.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/index.js:47:32)
    at async prepareFrameworks (/home/builds/7Wjzy3dMG/0/project-dir/node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-tools@13.22.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/frameworks/index.js:192:25)
    at async deploy (/home/builds/7Wjzy3dMG/0/project-dir/node_modules/.pnpm/firebase-tools@13.22.1_encoding@0.1.13/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:58:13)
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.

here is my .firebaserc
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "my-project"
  },
  "targets": {
    "my-project": {
      "hosting": {
        "prd": [
          "production"
        ],
        "stg": [
          "staging"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "etags": {},
  "dataconnectEmulatorConfig": {}
}

here is my firebase.json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firebase/firebase-tools/master/schema/firebase-config.json",
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
}


i'm assumming the No OAuth tokens found is the issue, but i already set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var in my ci cd, and it's still doesn't work
here is my ci
deploy-stg:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      changes:
        - '**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}'
        - '.firebaserc'
        - firebase.json
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
  script:
    - touch credential.json && cp "$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT" credential.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=./credential.json
    - export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./credential.json
    - cp "$DOT_ENV_STAGING" .env
    - nvm use 20 && pnpm install --no-frozen-lockfile
    - pnpm exec firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
    - pnpm exec firebase deploy --only hosting --debug
  tags:
    - gcp-shared


I think the problem is with your credential.json file in the CI. The error "Unexpected end of JSON input" means it's trying to read a JSON file that's empty or broken.
In your script, you use cp "$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT" credential.json. But if $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT has the JSON content itself, cp won't work because it copies files, not text.
Try this instead: echo "$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT" > credential.json. This writes the JSON content into the file.
Also, make sure $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT actually has your credentials and is set up right in your CI environment.
Double-check that the service account has all the permissions it needs to deploy to Firebase. let me know if it helps.

but my GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT is a file in my gitlab ci cd variable, and previously i also use that trick in my other project, but somehow this project is not working
